# gmail tracker with pxl image cant detect user-agent and ip

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, tracking

I having a problem detect the user agent and ip with img tracker.

**https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/gyZDQCAeDhyhynYAX5jGk0o8UAm7QuAGqE6U8N5QlQhZfhfhf8CzdokmOf7MPVwNjR9jRbExPkScYgPED_Ucr9zLSijkA8YwbAt7_sNZjIJoq8NSsHKwfN3252MLrx9ww=s0-d-e5-ft#**https://my-server-url.com/tracker/cleardot.gif?pxl=jCfzw9QB.

google add a proxy url for serving the image. i dont see it possible to overcome this issue. but on the other hand streak extension show location and user agent in their tracker. it there a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Google, for performance and privacy reasons, has occasionally changed the way they handle included images (and, therefore, image trackers in email).

For example, see:  https://knowledge.hubspot.com/articles/kcs_article/email/how-does-gmail-s-image-caching-affect-open-metrics-in-hubspot

(Gmail changed their services to cache image in January 2014, and as result, this method of tracking stopped working for most cases).

And, as of this writing (early 2018), the prevailing sentiment seems to be toward more user privacy and less tracking, so any remaining methods for tracking the recipient's handling of an email (opens, etc.) are likely to stop working at some point.

Comment: The article you referenced is redirecting me to [hubspot.com/.../analyze-your-marketing-email-campaign-performance](https://knowledge.hubspot.com/articles/kcs_article/email/analyze-your-marketing-email-campaign-performance) (not as helpful as the one you must have been pointing to!)